# Sublime Text 3 Java autocomplete

Tags: java, autocomplete, ide, sublimetext2, sublimetext3

Lately I was seriously considering switching to Sublime Text 3 for all of my projects. Now that Sublime Text 3 has a *goto* definition feature it's definitely more useful. However, to be a happy programmer under Sublime I still need a proper Java auto completion. Sublime Text 2 has one - it is called *sublimejava*. Unfortunately this plug-in doesn't deliver the magic with Sublime Text 3.

Does anyone know if Sublime Text 3 has a working plug-in for Java autocomplete?

Answer (score 4):

Sublime 3 does have basic autocompletion for Java baked-in - if you start typing "pub", for example, it'll suggest "public". I'd also suggest looking at the [Javatar](http://spywhere.github.io/Javatar/) plugin, which adds things like automatic creation of classes, packages, and interfaces. The [QuickJava](https://sublime.wbond.net/packages/QuickJava) plugin might also be worth a look - it adds automatic creation commands for setters, getters, and constructors.

Answer (score 4):

You can try [JavaIME](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/JavaIME) for helping with package imports and [Java Imports Made Easy](https://github.com/tushortz/javaime) for method names completion.

Comment: JavaIME is great but it overrides the default autocomplete done by sublime. For example, when I type an already defined variable it does not show that variable in the autocomplete suggestions.

I think I should open an issue on the project's github page.

Comment: The link to Java Methods Completion is dead

Comment: @anon it's been merged into JavaIME